# comparing ids with has_many: through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve my objective for this code by removing at least one of the conditionals below, or removing the `confirmations.each do` block code. It feels like the `has_many :through`associations are forcing me to do this awkward code, but I'm assuming I'm most likely doing things the wrong way.

In the code below, we are on `views/appointments/show.html.erb`

Basically, if a user has confirmed that they are attending a appointment, I want to give them an option to cancel that confirmation. The first `if` statement checks if they're confirmed attendance.

Since it's possible that a user has confirmed attendance at more than one appointment, I then loop through all of the user's confirmations, which is the reason for the `confirmations.each do` code.

I then have to create the delete link for the confirmation of this @appointment, so in the second `if` statement i compare to make sure the appointment_id of the confirmation is the same as the @appointment.id of the page we're on.

```
<% if current_user.confirmations.map(&:appointment_id).include?(@appointment.id) %>

<% current_user.confirmations.each do |confirmation| %>
<% if confirmation.appointment_id == @appointment.id %>

<%= link_to "delete", confirmation_path(confirmation), method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> 

<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

User.rb

```
 has_many :confirmations
 has_many :appointments, through: :confirmations
```

Confirmation.rb

```
belongs_to :appointment
belongs_to :user
```

Appointment.rb

```
has_many :confirmations
has_many :users, through: :confirmations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fetch the confirmation for `@appointment` and `current_user` or nil if the user hasn't confirmed yet.

```
<% confirmation = @appointment.confirmations.find_by_user_id(current_user.id) %>
<% if confirmation %>
  <%= link_to "delete", confirmation_path(confirmation), method: :delete,
                                    data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> 
<% end %>
```

You should consider removing the query logic to a scope or model method.